# SingleViewProject crash on Android

Tags: gluon-mobile

I use a Samsung Galaxy S7 for my tests.

I don't understand why I compile and launch my gluon Applications on my phone, it crash. I tried with the SingleViewProject and I have the same problem.

The last week, I didn't have this problem.

my grade file

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'
dependencies {
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.1'
androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.1'
iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:2.1.1'
desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.1.1'
}

jfxmobile {
     android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = "/Users/Alexandre/Library/Android/sdk"
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'io.datafx.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
}
```

The stacktrace

```
    Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 20944
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Did not create correct launcher.
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find    /javafx.platform.properties on classpath.
```

Have you an idea to help me ?

Comment: In command line, from Android sdk path go to `platform-tools` and run `./adb logcat -v threadtime` with your phone plugged. Then run the app and you should find a stacktrace with the exception that causes the crash.

Comment: On your project root, can you run `/.gradlew --info android` and see if there is any error while creating the apk?

Comment: I found any errors

Comment: Did you build your app before and it was working? Have you changed anything after that? Does it run on desktop?

Comment: The application run on desktop and on an iPhone. Yes, the last week, I build some applications test (gluon samples), they worked on all platforms and now any application work on my phone. it is not specific to an application

Comment: So it fails now only on Android? If it is Android specific, can you check if you have updated the platform? Make sure you use platforms 21, 22 or 23. Don't use the platform 24.

Comment: I checked the platform and I tried an another SDK, It's not working. I tried to add this parameters (         buildToolsVersion = 21
         compileSdkVersion = 21
         minSdkVersion = 21
         targetSdkVersion = 21)
in the gradle file but it's not working too.

Comment: Can you check and post here what dependencies for Android you find in your project? I see `android.jar` and `jfxdvk-8.60.7.jar`, and the charm jars.

Comment: I have charm-2.1.1.jar and java.json-1.0.4, just that

Comment: Don't you see the Android folder? What is your IDE and its version? [This](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.2.0/images/netbeans/nb12-full.png) is what you should see (with updated versions)

Comment: I use Eclipse 4.5.2 http://imageshack.com/a/img923/7190/17YBJK.png
What can I do ?

Comment: Eclipse works normally, as the other IDEs, but it doesn't show all the dependencies. Can you try deleting the jfxdvk jar so it gets updated? It should be here:  /Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/jfxdvk/8.60.7

Comment: Oh, It's totally my fault, when I compiled for IOS, the gradle say me "jfxdvk.jar" are double and I renamed jfxdvk.jar to jfxdvk.old. Now It's OK, I will fix the IOS problem with an another solution. thank you for your valuable help !